# How can I change the currency of existing plans in stripe payment gateway?

Tags: php, stripe-payments, currency

I have issue as the below.

I have assinged my users to different plans with currency AUD.
But the actual requirement is to set the plans currency in USD.

Please anyone can suggest how to change the existing users to these current plans with USD currency?

```
$p = \Stripe\Plan::retrieve('plan_id');
$p->currency = "usd";
$p->save();
```

- Referenct link : https://stripe.com/docs/api/plans/update
- this is not working with my case.

Comment: Currently you will not able to change the plan's currency. However, what you could do is to create a new plan with the USD currency and update the subscriptions with the new plan instead. https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/update#update_subscription-items

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create new Stripe customers for your clients and new USD plans. Currently, Stripe only supports 1 currency per customer and cannot be changed after it has been set.

EDIT: [Here is the source of said information](https://support.stripe.com/questions/set-or-change-currency-for-an-invoice-or-customer-in-stripe-billing#:%7E:text=Changing%20the%20currency&text=The%20only%20way%20to%20change,task%20in%20the%20right%20currency.)

Comment: It will be nice to have a link to the source of this information